# Над или ЗА

Tags: приставка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать в отчете:

> Контроль над посещаемостью
> обучающимися учебных занятий.

или

> Контроль за посещаемостью...

или может

> Контроль посещаемости...

Comment: @filippovaelena, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

При отглагольном существительном - **контроль за чем.**

Д.Э. Розенталь. "Управление в русском языке"М., "ОНИКС 21 век", "Мир и образование",2003. Стр.76

**Привожу статью справочника полностью,оформление сохраняю.**

Контроль - 1.**за чем** (при отглагольных существительных). *Контроль за исполнением работ, за расходованием средств.* 2. **за чем** (при существительных, обозначающих действие или признак). *Контроль за работой станка;Контроль за качеством работы;Контроль за порядком в классе*. 3.**над кем-чем** (при отвлечённых и одушевлённых существительных). *Контроль над молодыми специалистами; Контроль над финансами; контроль над производством.* 4. **чего** (в официальной и профессионально-технической речи). *Контроль деятельности выборных органов;Контроль температуры в доменной печи;Контроль готовой продукции.*

Comment: При отглагольном существительном - контроль за чем.
Д.Э. Розенталь. "Управление в русском языке".
===
Нет, этот справочник Розенталя для ОТГЛАГОЛЬНЫХ существительных допускает оба варианта -- и "за", и "над". 

См.:
КОНТРОЛЬ 1. за чем и над чем (при отглагольных существительных). Контроль за (над) выполнением плана. Контроль за (над) расходованием средств.
http://upravlenie.academic.ru/732

Answer (score 1):

Лучше: ***контроль за посещаемостью***.

**Граудина** в книге "Грамматическая правильность русской речи" пишет, что в современном употреблении встречается и *контроль за чем,* и *контроль над чем,* и *контроль чего,* причём преобладает вариант *контроль за чем-нибудь.*

В ХIХ веке употреблялась конструкция *контроль над чем.* Позднее, вероятно под влиянием конструкций *наблюдение, надзор за кем, за чем,* возникло управление *контроль за чем.*

В ряде случаев оба названных варианта не различаются в употреблении: *контроль над выполнением -- контроль за выполнением; **контроль над посещаемостью -- контроль за посещаемостью*** и т. д. **В этом значении, когда зависимое существительное обозначает действие,** **в современной речи преобладает конструкция *контроль за чем*.**

Конструкция *контроль над чем* употребляется главным образом в тех случаях, когда зависимое существительное обозначает конкретный предмет: *контроль над финансами* (ср. *контроль за расходованием средств*).

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря грамматической сочетаемости, РАН, 2013 год:

Все три варианта возможны, например: контроль работы, контроль за качеством, контроль над расходами.

Ошибочным является только употребление предлога ПО: контроль по качеству.

Какой же вариант выбрать? А может быть, все зависит от того, кто производит контроль. Например, для учителя это "контроль посещаемости" как его ежедневная и постоянная обязанность. Для инспектора/директора - "контроль за посещаемостью", для министерства  - контроль над посещаемостью.

Таким образом, можно предположить, что всё зависит от ситуации и стиля, которые предопределяют использование беспредложного управления или применение предлогов ЗА и НАД в соответствии с их значением.